# Current ver of Passenger with Rails 1.2.6 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Due to a number of issues, my app is currently stuck in Rails 1.2.6-land. Converting it to Rails 2.3 is planned, but will be awhile.

Question: Does current Passenger support Rails 1.2.6? I've heard different things.

I'm currently using nginx and mongrels but 'dem dogs are getting tired.

Thanks!

Larry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, we are in 1.2.6-land as well and using passenger for staging and dev servers.